# Fatal error after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, joomla

I had a working instance of Civicrm on my Joomla 3 site. Now I updated to Joomla 4.
I don't think I should have had to update Civicrm, but I was getting a 500 error for Civicrm.  Therefore I followed the usual update procedures going from 5.63 to 5.71.1.

The database update generated a  500 and turning error reporting on I am getting

```
Warning: file_put_contents(xxxx/media/civicrm/templates_c/CachedExtLoader.bba06b40bfffc98f82be5c6c2465da63.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in xxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php on line 86

Fatal error: Declaration of Civi\Api4\CaseContact::getEntityTitle($plural = false) must be compatible with Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractEntity::getEntityTitle(bool $plural = false): string in /xxxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/CaseContact.php on line 26
```

(as well as a bunch of deprecation messages).

The only thing I see on the upgrade instructions is the possibility of deleted files.  Does anyone else have a clue?

I am on php 8.2.16 which is also a change with the update to Joomla 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ton of files were moved into core extensions in 5.64. It sounds like you still have the originals in the original places. I would replace your civi folder with a fresh copy.

Comment: That solved the 500 error, though now I have a `Class "Civi\Api4\PaymentProcessor" not found`  ... would that have been one of the files?

Comment: Well wait first I have to get the database upgrade to run. It's not 500-ing but not working either it seems.

Comment: Would need more info about what "not working" means but yes PaymentProcessor is one of the files.

Comment: It finally ran when I got rid of the files.  But for anyone else, I would also say, the upgrade automatically sets the configuration of Civicrm plugins to enabled, but until you get it all completed this will block access to your admin interface.  So go to your data base and manually change in the extensions table.